# Laravel 5: Get all passed data in view template

Tags: php, view, laravel-5, laravel-blade

The objective is that I want to passe **ALL** passed data from the controller to the view in one single global JavaScript variable, this is an example:

**In the controller**

```
index(){
 return veiw('path.to.view', ['data1' => $data1, 'data2' => $data2]);
}
```

**In the view**

```
<script>
   var _backendData = {!! $allData !!}
   //$allData should contain ALL the passed data from the controller
</script>
```

I to store the all recieved data from controller in $allData

Comment: var _backendData = {!! $data1 !!}

Comment: I want to get ALL the data that the controller passed to the view, not only $data1, I edited my post and added $data2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access all that data, you pass it as one item of the root array. Because those keys become the view variables.

```
return view('path.to.view', [
   'allData' => ['data1' => $data1, 'data2' => $data2]
]);
```

View:

```
<script>
    var _backendData = {!! $allData !!}
</script>
```

However this is not going to work properly. You should use JSON to pass data to JavaScript:

```
var _backendData = JSON.parse("{!! json_encode($allData) !!}");
```

Comment: Thank you for help, I thought about making all the data in one variable, but I was search for a more 'confortable' way

Answer (score 0):

Set it on the controller - 
Use a multi-dimensional array to pass the data and get it in blade file.

```
return view('path.to.view', ['allData' => ['data1' => $data1, 'data2' => $data2]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are returning an array of data then you can access the elements one by one as shown below. You cannot just assign PHP array to be JavaScript array.

```
return view('path.to.view', [
   'allData' => ['data1' => $data1, 'data2' => $data2]
]);
```

View:

```
<script>
    var _backendData = {!! $allData['data1'] !!}
</script>
```